# How to calculate the number of gaps between two dates in js

Tags: javascript, date

I have two date with time:

> YY:MM:DD hh:mm

This is the time period
I need to calculate gap and divide it into **'n'** equal parts.

*In order to build a graph*

Pls Help

Comment: Can you be more specific.

Comment: What do you mean by 'gap'?

Comment: Possible duplicate of; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/542938/how-do-i-get-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates-in-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare two dates with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because date is actually saved as an integer and only shown as

```
YY:MM:DD hh:mm
```

You can actually just take the two date variables and devide them by the n

```
gap = (date1 - date2)/n
```

and then you can get the intervals by just adding the gap multiple times

```
for(var i = 1; i <= n; i++){
   newDate[i] = new Date(date2 + gap*i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

something like this?

you can operate directly with dates in javascript

```js
var date1 = new Date(2017, 01, 01, 10, 15, 00);
var date2 = new Date(2016, 12, 01, 10, 14, 45);

var dateDiff = new Date(date1-date2); //this will return timestamp 

var years = dateDiff.getFullYear() - 1970; //init date always is 1970
var months = dateDiff.getMonth();
var days = dateDiff.getDate();
var minutes = dateDiff.getMinutes();
var seconds = dateDiff.getSeconds();

alert(years + " years.\r " + 
      months + " months\r" + 
      days + " days\r" + 
      minutes + " minutes\r" + 
      seconds + " seconds");
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you try out the [momentjs](https://momentjs.com) library. It provides powerful functionalities for you to conveniently work with date objects.

For example, given 2 string dates that are properly formatted, you can get the precise difference between the 2 times easily like so:

```
let time1  = moment("04/09/2013 15:00:00");
let time2 = moment("04/19/2013 18:20:30");

let diffMilliseconds = time1.diff(time2); // gives the time difference in milliseconds
let diffDays = time1.diff(time2, 'days'); // gives the time difference in days
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the date object to convert the given time format to timestamp and then find difference between timestamp.
For example:

```js
var date1 = "2017-03-04 11:22:22"
var date2 = "2017-03-04 13:11:42"

var timestamp1 = Date.parse(date1, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
var timestamp2 = Date.parse(date2, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")

var difference = timestamp2 - timestamp1;

console.log(difference) //in milliseconds
```

Now you can divide the `difference` in to n parts and add to timestamp1 to get following **timestamp** based on `difference/n` interval.